# How do we implement Authentication Sync in React Native?

Tags: react-native, authentication, access-token

How do everyone store their authentication details in the app on programming through react native.... Do all of you store only the Access token and get new access token on intervels using refresh token or you all store the authentication details on offline such as using Asynchstorage to get fresh token on every expiry of the token.. please someone guide me to the right way!... Thanks

Comment: This is a very application specific thing and depends on so many different variables that it is tough to give a 1 solution fits all answer.  What i have done in the past is store it locally and then pass it on every request and on every request i return a new token.  So if a token has expired that next request will prompt a new authentication request for a new token.  This is where you would make them login again.  If this is a 1 time login with a lifetime token then that is a bit easier but same idea pass lifetime token and then updated requests tokens to validate the requests.

Comment: @jgetner Thanks for your reply. Most of the Apps we come across does not log out unless logged out by the user. I wonder how they work . Like is there any security issues on storing the authentication credentials offline or is there any advantage like storing a lifetime token

Comment: I would not store the credentials locally and i would probably advise not to store the token locally ether.  If the device is ever transferred to a new owner and they did not delete your app.  That account is now open for compromise due to the token being stored locally.  This becomes a big pain in the butt to solve.  But this is a user error.  This is where integration with another service such as google sign in becomes handy.  So when the account changes you can then force a new auth on your app.   If that makes sense.  This as i said is very application specific